# Nice approximations of sums by integrals.

Tags: calculus, integration, functional-analysis, summation, elementary-functions

Let $f(x):\Bbb Z^+\rightarrow \Bbb R^+$ be a non-monotone function.

If for every $m\in\Bbb N$, $$S(m) =\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{(1+f(n))^m}$$ be sum of interest, then is there a way to approximate this summation using integrals?

Comment: Is $f$ monotonic?

Comment: Does that help here?

Comment: You might also consider the generating function $G(z) = \sum_{m=0}^\infty S(m) z^m = \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1+f(n)}{1+f(n)-z}$.

Comment: @GregMartin How does that help here?

Comment: No idea. But you didn't say what you wanted to learn about the sums, so I don't know what "help" would mean anyway.

Comment: @GregMartin changed help to approximate. any case how does this GF change to integration?

Comment: Have you tried using the Euler-Maclaurin summation formula? A Google search will give further details (http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler–Maclaurin_formula)